# Exclude a JSP from web.xml's security-contraint

Tags: java, security, jsp, tomcat, web

I would like to exclude only one JSP file `question.jsp` from `security-constraint`.

I have this from my **web.xml**:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>My Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>      
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>      
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: You can create a folder and put everything else (except question.jsp) in that folder and use that pattern e.g. `/securefolder/*.jsp`.

Comment: I have so much JSPs so it's so much risky. is there another solution?

Answer (score 25):

Just add a free-pages section, without providing any auth-constraint. It will take precedence over protected pages:

```xml
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>free pages</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/question.jsp</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: [This blog entry](http://blog.mafr.de/2011/04/17/excluding-pages-from-auth/) is a good write up about the topic. You need a pattern that is more specific than the secure one in order to get some resources public.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to move all your secure JSP content to a specific directory path (say /protected/ from web root) and then your web.xml content will look like :

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>My Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>      
        <url-pattern>/protected/*.jsp</url-pattern>
```

You may leave your public JSPs on default docroot or to some other directory path as required.

Comment: thank you for your reponse, i thought about this solution, but i can't apply it, i have so much JSPs so it's so much risky. is there another solution?

Comment: @naj_ib I am failing to understand why you consider it riskier than just mentioning `*.jsp`

Comment: because the web project is very big and i dont need to operate that solution for just one jsp

Comment: Yes, so the best way would be to separate your secure vs non-secure file by means of path. And apply different security constraint to artifacts in different paths as mentioned in my answer.