# I need an example of a web.xml which lists a few pages which are CONFIDENTIAL and defaults everything else to NONE

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, ssl

In Tomcat, I can `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` and I can `<transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>`. I need an example of a web.xml which lists a few pages which are `CONFIDENTIAL` and defaults everything else to `NONE`. All help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need an example, this should be straightforward?

Comment: I have an example (working now) that does the HTTPS (CONFIDENTIAL) correctly. However, every time someone leaves an HTTPS page, they stay in HTTPS mode for insecure pages, which is a big speed loss. I have no test environment, so any security change would be live. I want to be sure I know the exact sequence of the web.xml

Comment: http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-ssl tells me how to make everything insecure. My current site has the correct web.xml to make the secure pages secure. I just need the intersection of these two ideas so that everything defaults to insecure **except** the already proscribed pages.

Comment: You really should create a test environment - it's easy to setup on a desktop...

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477755/exclude-a-jsp-from-web-xml but it does not seem to work for me on Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from your comments:

> I have no test environment

Create one. Really. Having no test environment is like saying "I don't care about even the most basic rules of engineering".

> every time someone leaves an HTTPS page, they stay in HTTPS mode for insecure pages, which is a big speed loss

Get a bigger/better server. Doing HTTPS should not be noticeable anymore today. There are plugins for the main browsers which try to make any connection via HTTPS for security reasons. So consider putting a few bucks into better hardware instead of compromising security for everyone.

PS: Yes, I'm aware that [the whole SSL certificate process could be more secure](https://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9219663/Hackers_may_have_stolen_over_200_SSL_certificates).

Comment: Aaron, I agree that we need a test server, however, I don't make those decisions about the use of my time here. I support several  production servers where I face this same limit. In IT we can advocate, but we can't often dictate. Also, while HTTP vs HTTPS hasn't caused me problems with Apache, I do see it with Tomcat. The server is new, cloud-based, and beefy compared to the load. I still see three to one differences serving the same page HTTP vs. HTTPS, even with the cache cleaned between.

Comment: What stops you from setting up a test environment in your own machine?

Comment: One word: time. I have two full time jobs. The work I do on Tomcat is a small part of one of those jobs. There is no admin or any other full time staff for this project. Of course, not one bit of the test server discussion helps me answer the original question: can someone give me a working example of how to get the insecure pages back from HTTPS to HTTP while still using relative links?

Comment: you didn't say anything about relative links until now :-) The answer is: You can't. To change the protocol, you need an absolute URL. For you (as a human), `http:` and `https:` are similar but for a computer, they are completely different.

Comment: This seems to be commentary on the question, rather than an attempt to answer it.